# How to extract this particular string using Unix/Awk/grep

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep

I have a log file which somewhat looks like this

```
Connected to feeder version 2.1 09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 01234567EUR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 0123456755JPY
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 0123426567INR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012345698887USD
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Loading Account 012343422567EUR
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 0234456783388KRY not set up
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Account 0234454467888CNH not set up
09:28:30 29/03/2014 Error : Closing Balance of Account 02344567888GBP Doesn't match
```

I want to extract the account numbers where there is a closing balance mismatch or if the account is not set-up and put those accounts into a new file for my further processing.The first step is i have used grep -il 'not set up' but after that how do I extract the account numbers, The pattern seems to be very random(not sure if I can use awk based on delimeter) Only pattern that is for sure is last 3 characters of an account Number is currency. So is it possible to use egrep and regex for this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '
/not set up/ {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if($i~/Account/) print $(i+1)":Not Set Up" > "Review.txt"
}
/Error/ {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i~/Account/) print $(i+1)":Mismatch" > "Review.txt"
}' file
```

This creates the following file:

```
$ cat Review.txt
0234456783388KRY:Not Set Up
0234454467888CNH:Not Set Up
02344567888GBP:Mismatch
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer, works like a charm.I was about to make this more complicated by using egrep and ending up nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use sed, without grep:

```
sed -n "
    s/.* Closing Balance of Account \(.*\) Doesn't match/\1/p;
    s/.* Account \(.*\) not set up/\1/p
  "
```

Adjust to taste, e.g. if you want to print something next to either case to identify which accounts have which problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, works superb. Basically these are the sub-account numbers which I have to lookup in the database and get the main account numbers and then add a comment/Reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grep statements as follows to get the desired account numbers:

```
grep 'not set up' file.txt | grep -Po '\d+[A-Z]{3}'
grep 'Error' file.txt | grep -Po '\d+[A-Z]{3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, shortish from the command line, just the account numbers:

```
awk -F'^.*Account|[ \t]*' '/Error|set/{print $3}' file
```

Or together with the reason:

```
awk -F'^.*Account[ \t]*' '!/Loading/{print $2}' file
```